# Can we check whether call forwarding is on or not on iOS Device Programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an App design and I want to add call forwarding detection as a feature, is there any way we can detect it? I checked it online but didn't find any solution to it.

I tried looking on ChatGPT but did not find any reliable solution to it.

Comment: No. This is actually a telephone network feature. There is no api for this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.